# Rspec - where is the extra configuration for test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am using the default `test` for different purposes and I have decided to make a specific `rspec` environment configuration for running the test suite.

However, I discovered that upon changing to `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= rspec` in my `rails_helper.rb` file, suddenly a LOT of things are going wrong, constants are not being loaded (FactoryGirl, DatabaseCleaner, etc. throw `uninitialized constant` errors)

My question is, where is the code that loads those guys in test environment ? Since I am planning to use this stage for other purposes than running automatic tests, I'm afraid this "out of nowhere" added configuration might not work well with what I am planning to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting `uninitialized constant` errors for FactoryGirl, DatabaseCleaner etc, you most likely included them to `test` group in your `Gemfile`.

You should move them to `rspec` group, eg:

```
# Gemfile

group :rspec do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'faker'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of Rails, the test environment is configured and loaded like any other environment such as `production` or `development`. You can see this prefixing `RAILS_ENV=test` to many of the native Rails commands e.g. `RAILS_ENV=test rails c` will load the rails console for the test environment, and so on. Similarly, all test-specific configuration within Rails is defined in `test.rb` in your `config/environments` folder.

*However*, when you run your specs with `rspec spec`, you're actually starting the RSpec runner, which, for most intents and purposes, runs independently of Rails (even with the `rspec-rails` gem).

By convention, when RSpec starts the first thing it does is read command line args from the `.rspec` in the current directory, if it exists. Then it runs `spec_helper.rb` (and also `rails_helper.rb` for `rspec-rails` 3+). It's actually the `spec_helper.rb` which does all the heavy-lifting in loading the Rails environment for your tests, along with any of the modules you're using in tests, such as `DatabaseCleaner`, `FactoryGirl`, etc.

If you're wondering how RSpec hooks into Rails, the bulk of it is performed in this line, which bootstraps Rails.

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

Now, as to your question, without the `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'` statement, the above line will load Rails in the default environment (development), which isn't what you want, since any gems not in the `:test` group  will not be loaded, and `environments/test.rb` will not be loaded either.

**TL;DR**

Test configuration is handled by two files: `spec/spec_helper.rb` (sometimes named `rails_helper.rb`) and `config/environments/test.rb`. The former configures RSpec and any objects and modules which will be used specifically within the files used in `spec`, the latter configures your Rails app itself. Omitting `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= test` loads the development environment and gemsets instead of the test environment and gemsets, which is why you're getting a ton of errors.